# Is it safe to delete the Isolated Storage folders?

Tags: windows, cleaning

I've found a lot of files in this folder:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\assembly

These files seem to be used for Isolated Storage. Are they safe to delete?

If so, how do I delete them? I do not have permission to do so (even when logged in as administrator).

Comment: does anyone know how to find out which app is creating the IsolatedStorage? digging into mine, I noticed the file is vsls - which seems to refer to vscode live share

Answer (score 2):

Isolated storage is used to provide per machine, per user or per app storage. It's probably not a good idea to delete it as some app is probably using it to store information.

Comment: Why do users always want to delete things......

Comment: haha I think the counter argument would be 'why do programs add so much crap'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it´s a good idea to move (not to delete) the content of this folder to another hard drive and try if everything works as expected. In that case you have some free disk space to enjoy. If not, you can move back the files to the folder.

Be careful with this kind of operations because there is a little chance of not letting the Windows to boot after restart, so always have another bootable media to be able to move back the files.